# C++11 type_traits : same type if floating point, double if integral type

Tags: c++, c++11, type-traits

I have a type `Type` and a variable `tmp` :

```
template<typename Type> myFunction()
{
    /* SOMETHING */ tmp = 0;
};
```

I would like to declare `tmp` as `Type` if `Type` is a floating-point type and as `double` if `Type` is an integral type. How to do that in C++11 ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
typedef typename std::conditional<
     std::is_floating_point<T>::value, 
     T,                                //if floating, ::type = T
     double                            //else,        ::type = double
>::type value_type;

value_type tmp; //declare variable
```

I'm assuming `T` can be only arithmetic type. If you want, you can use [`std::is_arithmetic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_arithmetic) to check that first.  See other helpful type traits here:

- [Type traits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types)

Answer (score 4):

Lookup and use the following traits:

```
template <bool, class T, class F> struct conditional;
template <class T> struct is_integral;
template <class T> struct is_floating_point;
```

If that doesn't do it for you, post what you've tried, and the resultant error message.